# mixAK::getProfiles help or bug?

Tags: cluster-analysis

Please could I have someone's views on the mixAK package getProfiles fn?

```
n <- 6
dat <- data.frame(id=rep((1:n), n/2), y = rnorm(n),
                  group=rep(LETTERS[1:2], n/2),
                  day=1:18,
                  x=rnorm(n))
library(mixAK)
ip <- getProfiles(t = "day", y = c("y", "x"), id = "id", data = dat)

ip
```

That doesnt seem right? Similar to the bug in a previous stackoverflow here:
[mixAK getProfiles bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31764315/mixak-getprofiles-bug)

Comment: Your post is rather vague. Could you reword your first sentence to ask a more specific question? What sort of views do you want to hear? What doesn't seem right about this?

Comment: (Could you add a language tag please to this - it will give you more exposure - is this R?).